# Bodhisattva Precepts

Tags: five-precepts

I've been really into the ethical and moral foundation of buddhism and stumbled onto the precepts. Would it be wrong of me to recite the bodhisattva precepts that I've found online that I identify with as a beginner to myself every morning?

Comment: I'm not sure why you might think there would be something wrong about it? It should be completely fine. If this is a question about copyright, try reading the answers to [this question.](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/2847/20268)

Comment: Do you mean the Bodhisattva Vow? Or do you mean the Five Precepts?

Answer (score 1):

At my last retreat, we recited the Bodhisattva vow quite frequently.

> Sentient beings are numberless; I vow to save them. Desires are
> inexhaustible; I vow to put an end to them. The Dharmas are boundless;
> I vow to master them. The Buddha Way is unattainable; I vow to attain
> it.

Not the precepts themselves, which were only recited by a preceptor when the precepts were being taken.

I would advise against regularly intoning them; it's an interesting question whether we can take them unofficially. Why not recite the nembutsu instead?

Comment: upvote so i have comment powers!